# Can't connect to Docker app when mapping volume

Tags: r, docker, rstudio-server

This is my docker file (built to `rs`):

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM rocker/rstudio:latest

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# install stuff
RUN apt update && apt install -y vim

# create user balter
USER root
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/balter -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 balter
RUN usermod -a -G rstudio balter
RUN chpasswd <<<balter:weakpass
```

When I launch it with

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8787:8787 --name rs rs
```

I can log in as `rstudio` or `balter`.

However, when I launch it with

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8787:8787 -v /home/balter:/home/balter --name rs rs
```

I can log in as `rstudio`, but I get the following error when I try to log in as `balter`:

[image: could not connect to the R session on RStudio Server]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8787:8787 -v /home/balter:/home/balter/ -e ROOT=TRUE -e USER=balter -e USERID=balter -e PASSWORD=weakpass --name rs rocker/rstudio:latest
```

user: balter /
pwd: weakpass

I have never tried to change the user, but could you see if this works for you and if yes, let me know

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to log in as `balter`

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: please, let me know if only with the USER parameter this works

Comment: When I use `--user balter`, then the browser tells me "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Comment: Same if I put `USER balter` at the end of the dockerfile.